# How to implement notification in Firefox OS?

Tags: html, notifications, firefox-os

I have an instant messaging application almost complete the only thing I'm missing are firefox notifications for you. As is the API?

Comment: Have you implemented Push notification in the Simulator ? Does it works ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear if you're after Notifications API or Push Notifications API, so I'll talk about both.

First, the Notification "API" (I'm not sure if it's been renamed to be an API, and I'm afraid it's just known as "Notification" by now). You can use [`mozNotification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/navigator.mozNotification) to create new notification objects and use [`show`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Displaying_notifications) to display them:

```
var notification = navigator.mozNotification;
 var n = notification.createNotification("Title", "Body", "optional_icon.png");
n.show();
```

On both links, you can get a better understanding what can be done with this.

Be sure you ask for permission to use this (add this to your `manifest.webapp`):

```
"permissions": {
    "desktop-notification":{}
}
```

To make it easier, I've made a [demo app](https://gitorious.org/firefox-os-demos/moznotification). That a look at how it works, and the changes I've made.

Warning: this is different from [Web Notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/).

The [Push API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/PushAPI) is already listed on Mozilla Wiki, but it's work in progress AFAIK. You can follow the news on this specific API on [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/PushAPI), on [github (server side stuff)](https://github.com/telefonicaid/notification_server) and on the [Gecko implementation bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763198).

There's another API, the [SimplePush API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/SimplePush), that seems to be working by now. Unfortunately, I don't know much about it. But at least the documentation seems pretty good.

Unfortunately again, I don't know how those APIs relate to [W3C's Push API](http://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/). I'm afraid the [Push API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/PushAPI) is somewhat related to the standard, although I'm not sure of that. I wouldn't rely on any other documentation besides Mozilla's, in the case of these APIs.

Comment: Your example works, but when I implement my application nothing happens. Not that I've done wrong. I have the manifest.webapp, the home page .php with the code <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/app.js" src="js/lib/require.js"> </script> and the folder /js and js/lib but it does not work ...

Answer (score 1):

For server based push notifications see [Simple Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Simple_Push) that includes implementation examples. **This is available in Firefox OS (/Boot2Gecko) 1.1. but not in 1.0** (which is on all currently released devices).
Please also note, that you'll need a real device and it won't work in the emulator.

Simple Push itself is not difficult to implement given the above link. Nevertheless there a couple of things you need to take care about:

- you need your own server that will trigger Firefox's server on demand for a push
- the push received on the device does not contain any information (this means you'll have to query needed information after receiving the push)
- the push received is silent and invisible - that means you'll have to display a desktop notification yourself as described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534867/986426)
- the push endpoint has to be the same page as your `launch_path` from the manifest (this means you'll have to put all the logic in one page) due to a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=800431)
- make sure you'll [acquire a wake lock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.requestWakeLock) after receiving the push and release it after your work is done - this way the device will not fall to deep sleep and your push processing is paused in the middle of it

It is possible to build similar functionality on Boot2Gecko 1.0 using [MozAlarmsManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozAlarmsManager).

Comment: Hi, Instead of using console.log , use alert. It works for me. I tried registering for push notifications. But error is called. Not sure whether it works in simulator

Comment: @Cyril Can you check in the settings, which Boot2gecko version your device is running? Which device is it by the way?

Comment: B2G 1.1.0.0-prerelease

Comment: Can you tell me now ?

Comment: Sounds like you have the nightly builds installed, not the stable, which explains why Simple Push is available (though it might not be working). I'll try the nightlies myself and see how it goes.

Comment: Updated my Geeksphone Keon to the latest nightly build running B2G 1.2. When trying my Simple Push code I receive successfully an endpoint upon register. Just have to play with that URL and see if it works, but so far so good. Try to update to the latest nightly ( https://geeksphone.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1159787-keon-flashing-guide ) and see if it works for you, too.

Comment: I know this simple push will work for sure when you try in the devices. Sadly, I don't have a device to test it. That's why I am trying to implement in Simulators.